# Can I use AREF to supply a circuit, when in internal mode? (Nano)

Tags: arduino-nano, pins

When `analogReference(INTERNAL)` is set (1.1V), can I use the AREF pin to supply a circuit? E.g. like this:

```
AREF —— R1 —— button switch —— A4 —— R2 —— GND
```

where A4 is configured as analog input (forming a resistive voltage divider with R1 and R2).

Is this safe to do? The reference manual talks about having a capacitator on AREF, or only capacitive loads.

You can find the [datasheet here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf): see 23.2 (page 205), Figure 23-1 (block circuit diagram, page 206), and section 23.5.2 (Page 211).

Comment: probably not ... what does the reference manual say about current sourcing capacity of the pin? ... please provide a link to the reference manual ... add link to the question ... do not add in a comment

Comment: @jsotola: It says “Note that VREF is a high impedance source, and only a capacitive load should be connected in a system.”

Comment: Unfortunately the ref manual does not mention sourcing capacities.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I would consider such usage of VREF out of spec. If you really need to do that you can use an opamp to build a voltage follower. That will preserve the voltage and also handle the direct current needed. Though I'm not sure what that does to the stability of the reference voltage (not an expert in analog signal handling)

Comment: Why not use the 5V output?

Comment: @chrisl: would you promote your comment as answer, please? Add Gils question. Good enough as answer. :-)